# Display table data using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i tried to filter data using angularJS but table didn't display the data
this is my script

```
var app = angular
          .module("myModule", [])
          .controller("myController", function ($scope) {

              var empolyee = [
              {name: "Amr",gender:  "Male", city:  "Cairo", department: "IT" },
              {name: "Ahmed",gender:  "Male",  city:  "Alexandira", department: "HR" },
              {name: "sara",gender:  "female",  city:  "Luxor", department: "CS" },
              {name: "Osama",gender:  "Male",  city:  "Assuit", department: "IT" },
              {name: "Farah",gender:  "female",  city:  "Cairo", department: "IS" },
              ];

              $scope.empolyees = empolyee;
          });
```

and this is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Script.js"></script>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        Search : <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search employees"/>
        <br /><br />
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td> {{  employee.name  }} </td>
                    <td> {{  employee.gender  }} </td>
                    <td> {{  employee.city  }} </td>
                    <td> {{  employee.department  }} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the result is 
{{ employee.name }} {{ employee.gender }}   {{ employee.city }} {{ employee.department }}
i want to display the data 
what's the problem ?!

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: The program '[8216] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8216] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>>>>>>>
the table is drawn but data is replaced with {{employee.row}}

Comment: Try opening Developer Tools. What do you see in the DevTools console?

Comment: U mean MDN ? then ?

Comment: No, Developer Tools. (Right Click -> Inspect)

Comment: include.preload.js:465 Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
init @ include.preload.js:465
Script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Script.js:2

Comment: "angular is not defined". Try to include Angular from CDN or try downloading Angular again.

Comment: thx ^^ worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$scope.employees = empolyee;
```

in place of

```
$scope.empolyees = empolyee;
```

you have a spelling mistake here  **$scope.empolyees** but in view it is **employees**

```js
var app = angular
  .module("myModule", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    
   

    var empolyee = [{
      name: "Amr",
      gender: "Male",
      city: "Cairo",
      department: "IT"
    }, {
      name: "Ahmed",
      gender: "Male",
      city: "Alexandira",
      department: "HR"
    }, {
      name: "sara",
      gender: "female",
      city: "Luxor",
      department: "CS"
    }, {
      name: "Osama",
      gender: "Male",
      city: "Assuit",
      department: "IT"
    }, {
      name: "Farah",
      gender: "female",
      city: "Cairo",
      department: "IS"
    }, ];

    $scope.employees = empolyee;            
                    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    Search :
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search employees" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Department</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees track by $index">
          <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.city }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.department }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the same result

Comment: @Amr : what changes you have made? check the snippet based on your code in the answer. it does work

Comment: the problem was i miss to add angular.min.js .. and your answer should be true else :) .. thx

Comment: Okk, thats why. I was surprised why it did not work for you.